# Postgresql gives strange performance

Tags: postgresql

I run a query on Postgresql 9.4, for two same structure dataset (same distribution but set2 has two times tuples than set1, and two times final result than set1). By execute explain analyze, I see both plan uses seq-scan and hash join.

1) the two plan are mainly same, except the order of tables' seq-scan;

2) the two plan takes similar time.

I don't understand why. I guess set2 should takes roughly two times set1?

The query plans are here :

http://explain.depesz.com/s/eJ0b

http://explain.depesz.com/s/RvRQ

Here is the query plan using buffer.

http://explain.depesz.com/s/b2f

http://explain.depesz.com/s/TLs

some other information:
I tested on 3 dataset. set3=2*set2=4set1
I saw from the query plan, they generated different hash bucket and batches.

Set 1: Buckets: 1024 Batches: 8 (originally 1) Memory Usage: 4097kB

Set 2: Buckets: 1024 Batches: 64 (originally 1) Memory Usage: 4097kB

Set 3: Buckets: 1024 Batches: 32 (originally 1) Memory Usage: 4097kB

Should't set 2 has smaller or equal batches than set 3 and larger or equal batches than set1 ?

Comment: You need to atleast post the output of both explains for a definitive answer. But they probably take about equal time because the same amount of data needs to be processed before it knows what rows you actually want.

Comment: @Eelke I have added the query plan.  Because set 2 has two times data than set 1, I think the amount of data are not same ?

Comment: Caching probably. Use `buffers` option to see how much data was retrieved from the cache: `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) ...`. And run the two explains several times (in different order), not just once.

Comment: The hash joins (in-memory) are faster with the second statement - not sure why that is the case. Could be the values that need to be hashed.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated the explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) result. I do not understand why the hash join takes similar time. The query are same, the data are same structure. just set 2 is larger than set1.

Comment: The plan with the larger result set has actually less rows in many of the preceding steps so even while the last step takes 1.7 sec against 1 sec it is more then that difference ahead when it gets there. I also noticed that at several steps the esitimated row number is quite small the actual row counts is quite high. You might need to update your table statistics.

Comment: @Eelke each test, I start the server, run sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3; and then import data, analyze, run my query and shutdown server. is there any step I missed to update the statics ?